# UDF as default value in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying use a sequence with a limited range as an ID column in a table. Right now, snowfalke does not support an upper limit on a sequence, so am thinking of using a UDF to get around this:

```
create or replace sequence seq1 with start = 1 ;

create or replace function seq1_with_max()
returns number
as 
$$
    select case when a.s < 10  then a.s else null end as id  from ( select seq1.nextval as s from dual ) a
$$
;

select seq1_with_max() ;

create or replace table f (
  id number not null default seq1_with_max(),
  c varchar 
) ;

insert into f(c) values ('a') ;
```

returns

```
SQL compilation error:    
syntax error line 1 at position 1 unexpected 'SELECT'.
syntax error line 1 at position 12 unexpected 'A'.
```

I don't quite understand why this isn't working. How could the UDF be modified to achieve the same goal?

Comment: I don't have a solution, but you've run into a few things that are in the documentation:  `If a default expression refers to a SQL user-defined function (UDF), then the function is replaced by its definition at table creation time. If the user-defined function is redefined in the future, this will not impact the column’s default expression.` And a default value can't include a subquery.  If you can figure out a way to not have a subquery in your UDF, it'll work.

Comment: The subquery portion in the doc I had missed. There is also something about a DEFAULT expression needing to be a SQL UDF , but I can't find now.

Comment: A default expression doesn't need to be a UDF, but it can be one.  It just can't contain a sub-select.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. This looks like snowflake create statement we cannot use UDF. I tried this instead.

```
create or replace table f (
  id number not null ,
  c varchar 
) ;

insert into f(id,c) select seq1_with_max(),'hello';

select * from f;
```

Comment: thing is, I don't think we can be limited to just `insert.. select` , suppose we wanted to load from stages, this approach doesn't  seem viable

Comment: Other types of UDFs, such as JavaScript UDFs and secure SQL UDFs, cannot be referenced in column default expressions. So I just tried a constant value and it works. If I add a select it does not work.